# OSMnx: angle between nodes

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, edges, osmnx

As I mentioned in the title I need to find the angle between nodes. I have a list of nodes with the ids of the nodes of a route. I have thought on doing it somehow using the 'x' and 'y' coordinates but I am not arriving at any conclusions.
Also, I've been told about using 'bearings', but again I don't really know how to use it, hence I don't get the proper result.

(I am using Networkx and OSMnx)

Being id_src and id_dst the ids of two consecutive nodes:

```
G.edges[(id_src, id_dst, 0)]['bearing']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import OSMnx

```
import osmnx as ox
```

Import the graph of Melbourne

```
address_name='Melbourne'
G=ox.graph_from_address(address_name, distance=50)
```

Create `nodes` and `edges` geodataframes from the graph

```
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=True)
```

Calculate edge bearings and make a pandas series out of them

```
import pandas as pd
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)
bearings = pd.Series([data['bearing'] for u, v, k, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)], name='bearing')
```

Concatenate the series with the `edges` geodataframe to have the edge bearings in the same `edges` geodataframe

```
edges = pd.concat([edges, bearings], axis=1)
```

Example:

```
print('Bearing between nodes '+str(edges['u'][0])+' and '+str(edges['v'][0])+' is '+str(edges['bearing'][0]))
```

*`Bearing between nodes 6167413263 and 6167441066 is 69.48`*

You may use the following function for calculation of bearings between any two nodes, although it does not entirely match up with the calculated bearings, but is fairly accurate.

```
def bearing(G,node1,node2):
    import math
    node1lat = nodes.at[node1, 'y']
    node1lon = nodes.at[node1, 'x']
    node2lat = nodes.at[node2, 'y']
    node2lon = nodes.at[node2, 'x']
    londiff = node2lon - node1lon 
    print('londiff: '+str(londiff))
    latdiff = node2lat - node1lat
    print('latdiff: '+str(latdiff))
    if latdiff > 0 and londiff > 0: # Quadrant1
        bearing = 90.0 - math.degrees(math.atan2(latdiff,londiff))
    elif latdiff < 0 and londiff > 0: #Qaudrant2
        bearing = 90.0 - math.degrees(math.atan2(latdiff,londiff))
    elif latdiff < 0 and londiff < 0: #Qaudrant3
        bearing = 90.0 - math.degrees(math.atan2(latdiff,londiff))
    elif latdiff > 0 and londiff < 0: #Qaudrant4
        bearing = 450.0 - math.degrees(math.atan2(latdiff,londiff))

    return bearing
```

Comment: So now I've tried this, but what should I do to get the angle between two specific nodes? (Sorry, I'm bad at this).

Comment: For starters, you can never have an angle between 2 nodes. You will need 3, that is 2 lines between which you calculate the angle. What you can have is bearings which for each edge (an angle, since a reference line is set). That is what my code did, assign the bearing of each edge and put it in the dataframe. Each row in that dataframe represents an edge, with u and v representing its end nodes. So in a row you have the osm id for an edge, its 2 end nodes, and the bearings. That's what you wanted. And my code does that as well.

Comment: For calculating the bearing between any 2 nodes (may not necessarily be the end nodes of an edge) you can define a new function and use it.

Comment: Refer here for the calculation used in the OSMNx package. https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/osmnx/utils_geo.py

Answer (score 2):

If by angle you mean bearing, then you can use the [add_edge_bearings](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_geo.add_edge_bearings) function to get the bearing of each edge (i.e., from node `u` to node`v` if `u` and `v` are adjacent in the graph). This gives each edge an absolute bearing attribute, that is, the angle (from the source node) between north and the destination node.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', network_type='drive')
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)
gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
gdf_edges[['u', 'v', 'bearing']].head(1)
# returns 53090322 53090323 140.383
```

In this example, we can see that the [bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)) from node 53090322 to node 53090323 is 140.4 degrees.